# How to pack frame below the top frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a frame at the top right corner which has been packed using the following code:

```
self.checkbuttonframe = tk.LabelFrame(self,text = 'Selected Required Visualization') 
self.checkbuttonframe.pack(side = 'left', anchor = 'nw', pady = 10,padx = 10)
```

I want to pack another frame below it using this code:

```
self.countrycheckbuttonframe = tk.LabelFrame(self)
self.countrycheckbuttonframe.pack(side = 'bottom', anchor = 'nw', pady = 10,padx = 10, fill = 'both')
```

And then place the following label in that second frame

```
self.textval = 'Selected Countries:'
self.selectcountries = tk.Label(self.countrycheckbuttonframe, text = 'Selected Countries:', relief = 'raised')
self.selectcountries.pack()
```

However I do not get the bottom frame to display. The image shows what I'm getting. How do i get the second frame `countrycheckbuttonframe` to show up? Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you don't have a lot of code,you can post it.Or you can show us a minimal example?

Comment: ***How to pack frame below the top frame?***: It's the default using `.pack`, remove any `side=` options.